# For loop to generate character pattern

Tags: java

I am trying to generate the following pattern using for loops in java.

```
"+-*+-*+-*+" and "+++***------***+++"
```

I am not sure how i can generate the last "+" at the end of the pattern.

My current code looks like this:

```
int j;   
for(j=0;j<3;++j) {
        System.out.print("+-*");
}    
for(j=0;j<2;++j) {
        System.out.print("+++***---");
}
```

How would I print the first half of the second pattern and reverse it to produce the pattern above?

Comment: What are the source strings of these patterns, *before* you expand them to what you want?

Answer (score 0):

A small observation that in first string "+-*" only these 3 characters or string are repeating and you can simply use modulus and solve it

You can do something like this:

```
String pattern1 = "+-*";
for(int i=0; i < lengthOfPattern; i++){
     System.out.print(pattern1.charAt(i%3));
}
```

for second pattern again you can see that first you are print "+++***---" and then reverse of it alternatively. And Iguess this this will go on. Again

```
String pattern2 = "+++***---";
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++){
    if(i%2==1){
        System.out.print(pattern2);
    }else{
        System.out.print(new StringBuilder(pattern2).reverse().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    System.out.print("+-*");
System.out.print('+');
String    s = "+*-*+";
for (int i = 0; s[i]; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        System.out.print(s[i]);
```

something like that maybe
(I did not test this code)